# How to read a nested Python object/class in C code?

Tags: python, c

**I will divide the question into two parts**

Part I:
Let’s say I have a python class `A`. And this object `A` is pass to a C code. I want the C code to read `A.data` and `A.index` (which are just integers or doubles) and how would I do it? I try using `PyArg_ParseTuple` function, but it doesn't work well. All I need here is for the C function to read the data and the index in `A`.

```
#include "Python.h"

int function(PyObject *A)
{
    double data; // data <- A.data
    int index; // index <- A.index
    // code here
}
```

Part II: If `A` is now instead a list of objects, how do I read `A[0]` from it in C code? I have a code like the following:

```
PyObject * read(PyObject *A)
{
    PyObject * out;
    PyArg_ParseTuple(A[0], "O", out);
    return out;
}
```

But the compiler fails.

Comment: How to extract data from a Python object depends on what type it is (or what protocol can be applied). You should expose (i.e. [edit] into the question) how your Python object is defined in Python.

Comment: @Scheff's Cat I fixed the typo. You can think of the object like a matrix and each matrix element contain data and index.

Comment: _You can think of the object like a matrix_ Then I would use the resp. protocol to extract the intended data from the Python object e.g. the [Iterator Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/iter.html). - Sorry, that's not how the site is working. Concrete question -> hope for answer. Wishy washy -> down votes (at best).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PyObject_GetAttr](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr) or [GetAttrString](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttrString).

For iterable objects, use [PyObject_GetIter](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetIter).

Comment: Now if I want the j th element of `A` what should I do?

Comment: Then use [PySequence_Fast](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast) to read the object A and [PySequence_Fast_GET_ITEM](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast_GET_ITEM) to get the i-th element of A.